# Licensing with 2 SQL Server databases

Tags: sql, oracle, multiplexing

1) If I have a mobile application database written in SQL Server which has SQL Server CE databases on PDAs synchronising with it, can I get away with no licensing cost if I use the SQL Server Express Edition?

2) SQL Server <> SQL Server (Mobile Application Database) <> SQL CE
If we then complicate the model as the mobile application main SQL Server database has a service runninhg which then synchronises via .NET and web services to another database that is SQL Server based, does this cause problems with licensing, e.g. in the area of multiplexing because we know our ultimate end PDA users?

3) Oracle <> SQL Server (Mobile Application Database) <> SQL CE 
How would licensing be affected if the backend system is changed to Oracle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Express Edition is free to use - it's got it's limitations but if your app can work inside it's constraints then it's fine to use.

You're not clear on point 2 but if all of those SQL installations are Express or CE/Compact then that's fine as well.

You license costs would come in if you put a Standard/Enterprise edition SQL Server in the mix at which point you either need to look at CAL licensing or get Proc license(s).

Comment: Thanks.  Thats good to know for sure.  Thanks for confirming it.

Comment: In terms of point 2.  Ultimately jobs are created in the backend system and synchronised to the Mobile Database.  These are then synchronised to the individual PDAs.  The concern was that in Microsoft's eyes, the PDAs ultimately are known users of the backend system and therefore irrespective of the licensing on the middle tier, their user count has to be added to the backend licensing count under multiplexing rules.

Comment: You're still not clear on this. What type of server is the backend system? If your backend system is using SQL Server Standard or Enterprise edition then YES you do need to license the individual users/devices - you can't "hide" the number of clients by multiplexing through your middle tier as you refer to it.  If you're backend is running SQL Express then there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

If SQL Express will meet your needs then there shouldn't be any licensing issues.

If you use a version of SQL that requires licensing you have to get CAL's for your known users, or go the per-CPU licensing route which doesn't require CAL's.

Comment: Thanks.  So there are no issues even though ultimately the job data from the users comes from the backend SQL Server system?  There are no issues with the application seen a multiplexed?  Thanks.

Comment: Incorrect, I said you would need CAL's for all your users or need to license the backend on a per-CPU basis to avoid the need for CAL's.